# Onclick property not working for link (a href)

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm developing an android app with phonegap and I have a table with some data. When clicking on a row it should go back to index and fire a function, so I turn each row into an html `a href` with a `onclick` property. The problem is that the `href` it's working and it goes back to the index but ti doesn't fire the function. Here's the code that generates the table and the code of the function:

```
function doLocalStorage(xyz) {
        alert(xyz);
    }

<table id="hor-minimalist-b"><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>
    <script language="javascript">
    var table = document.getElementById('hor-minimalist-b'); // get the table element
    var tableBody = table.childNodes[1]; // get the table body
    var tableHead = table.childNodes[0]; // get the table head
    var thead = document.createElement('th');
    var row2 = document.createElement('tr'); // create a new row
    var headText = document.createTextNode('Dados');
      thead.scope = "col";
        thead.appendChild(headText);
        row2.appendChild(thead);
        tableHead.appendChild(row2);

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {

        var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create a new row

        var cell = document.createElement('td'); // create a new cell
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var cellText = document.createTextNode(localStorage.getItem('key' + i));
        var xyz = localStorage.key(i);
        a.href = "index.html";
        a.onclick = "doLocalStorage(xyz);";
        a.appendChild(cellText);
        cell.appendChild(a); // append input to the new cell
        row.appendChild(cell); // append the new cell to the new row
        tableBody.appendChild(row); // append the row to table body
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One you should really be using jQuery as it will take care of browser inconsistencies for you.

Two, you'll likely need to use onlick like this.

```
a.onclick = function() { doLocalStorage(xyz); };
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you explain me how to use jQuery in this case? I'm kind of new on android and javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just goto the jQuery website or Google many of tutorials online. There is many beginner tutorials out there. Working with localstorage you will probably be fine just to work with it directly, but for handling events, traversing the DOM, and DOM manipulation jQuery is a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete a href attribute and handle a click event with redirection `window.location.href = ('url')`. It should help.